# Why is my tableview jittery when I scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

A tablview cell is being setup using the following code...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    MyTableviewcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mytableviewcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [self.data[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];
    cell.taxonomy1Label.text = [self.data[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"group"];


    @try {
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.data[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The `try/catch` are just because it may or may not have an image but it was happening even before I put that in. It seems like there is some sort of issue when it goes to dequeue the cell. Any ideas?

Comment: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] is causing the lag. You should do that in a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with using third party libraries or CocoaPods, but this is a common problem, and I recommend the use of https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage or https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking, which have UIImageView category methods to handle loading images from a URL in the background, and not in a main thread.

For example using SDWebImage:

```
[cell.thumbnailImageView sd_setImageWithURL:yourImageURL];
```

This method will fetch the image in the background, not blocking the main thread and will not make your UITableView jitter.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned this call blocks the main thread:

```
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.data[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]];
```

What wasn't already mentioned is the right way to handle this kind of work.

You can't just wrap the above in a [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) call and expect everything to be OK.

You need to lazy load the images and populate them on the tableView when appropriate.

The most elegant way to handle this is to write your own **`NSOperation`**.

[Here](http://www.macspotsblog.com/asynchronous-image-loading-for-uitableviewcells/) is a tutorial, any further questions let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You are obstructing the main thread by trying to fetch image. Put your image call in a separate thread.